# Inline CSS works, external doesn't (JsFiddle included)

Tags: html, css, background-color

http://jsfiddle.net/xw0vvo9e/4/

I'm attempting to set a background color for my navBar. As you can see in the jsfiddle, I have:

```
div .navBar {
width: 100%;
height: 45px;   
background-color: #FF0000; 
top: 0px;
position: fixed;
}
```

and it doesn't work. However, if I remove it, and change the HTML to:

```
<div class="navBar" style="background-color:#FF0000;">
```

it works just fine. I've been scratching my head on this for quite some time now.

Comment: Ignore the stuff about being logged in and all that jazz. It's just php stuff. My navbar problem has persisted for a few days now and I've chosen to just move on, but now I'm faced with a situation in which I want to be able to change it, and I finally have to tackle this problem. >_<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the space in your selector, i.e. it should be `div.navBar`. Your current selector which is a [*descendant combinator selector*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#descendant-combinators) tries to find `.navBar` descendants of the `div` elements. As the `.navBar` element doesn't have any `div` parents/grandparents the selector fails to select the target element.

Comment: agh! I can't believe I looked that over. I feel so silly now.. lol

Thank you.